# Javascript array index error

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, menuitem

I am trying to access to a simple nested Array, doing this:

```
var currMenu = 1;
    while ( currMenu < menu.length ) {
        alert(currMenu);
        alert(menu[0][currMenu].text);
        currMenu++;
}
```

Despite alerts are throwing the correct values, I am getting this error on firebug: TypeError: menu[0][currMenu] is undefined.

What is happening?

Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, I was rushing, here you have the "menu" structure:

```
menu[0] = new Array();
menu[0][0] = new Menu(false, '', 15, 50, 20, '','' , 'navlink', 'navlink');
menu[0][1] = new Item('someText', '#', '', 100, 10, 1);
```

And the object Item:

```
function Item(text, href, frame, length, spacing, target) {
    this.text = text;
    if (href == '#') {
        this.href = '#';
    } else if (href.indexOf('http') == 0) {
        this.href = href;
    } else this.href = href;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.length = length;
    this.spacing = spacing;
    this.target = target;
    // Reference to the object's style properties (set later).
    this.ref = null;
    this.showLoadingBar = false;
}
```

Comment: Now what do we know about menu value?

Comment: sure you dont mean `menu[currMenu].text` ?

Comment: Sorry again, there is more data and object structure

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your menu is coherent with the `[0][currMenu]`, you should access it like this :

```
while ( currMenu < menu[0].length ) {
    alert(currMenu);
    alert(menu[0][currMenu].text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the length of the "menu" array, but you're *accessing* the array at the zero-th index of that array (which may or may not be an array; I can't tell from the code you've posted).